# Placement of axis labels at minor breaks with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` to do some plotting of genomic data, so the basic format is that there is a chromosome and a position along it.  I convert the positions to be on a continuous scale, then put the breaks at the boundaries of the chromosomes with:

`scale_x_continuous("Genome Position", breaks = c(0, cumsum(chromosome_length)))`

That looks great, as far as the actual plotting is concerned, but the labels are then put at the start and end of the chromosomes.  I would like them to be centered along each chromosome, at the position where the minor break is drawn by default.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
breaks <- c(0, cumsum(chromosome_length))
scale_x_continuous("Genome Position", breaks = breaks + 0.5, labels = breaks)
```

Comment: Not so much.  Aside from the fact that breaks + 0.5 would not put them in the correct place, this is just moving the major breaks, rather than labeling the minor breaks, which is what I would prefer to do.

Comment: Well you can't label the minor breaks, but you can easily simulate the effect by moving the major breaks, adjusting the theme and using geom_vline.  Try the ggplot2 mailing list.

Comment: Impossible labeling the minor ticks: Is this justified or a conceptual bug. At first sight it seems obvious that you want to do that, for example Mayor=years minor=months

Comment: There is an infinite number of things that seems "obvious" to someone - I can only implement and support a finite number

Comment: @hadley This would be very useful, though. Plot.ly has added it, and I can't stop using it anymore.

Comment: I've been searching for such answer for an hour...