# ggplot2: dates - anyway to plot years on major x axis and months on minor x-axis?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

Here's an image I made in paint on what I'm trying to do

[image]

Basically I'm trying to plot years on the major x axis and months on the minor x axis. And every three months (March, June,September,December) have a vertical broken line. I have really no clue where to start.

I'm not even sure if it is possible. I'm not sure if Hadley was addressing a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554942/placement-of-axis-labels-at-minor-breaks-with-ggplot2). Some wrote "

Impossible labeling the minor ticks: Is this justified or a conceptual bug. At first sight it seems obvious that you want to do that, for example Mayor=years minor=months" and hadley responded

> There is an infinite number of things that seems "obvious" to someone
>   - I can only implement and support a finite number

...so I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible in ggplot2.

Comment: Probably not, but you could get pretty close using `facet_wrap`, and adjusting how close the facets are to each other (`theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, 'lines'))`) and also using `strip.position = 'bottom'`

Comment: Related: [Prevent showing the year several times unnecessarily with time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616530/prevent-showing-the-year-several-times-unnecessarily-with-time-series)

Comment: @Henrik almost seems like a duplicate??

Comment: Thanks Henrik! That was exactly what I was looking for!