# R ggplot2: labels on time axis to monthly bins

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am trying to adjust the way ggplot labels the axis. My code is:

```
x = as.POSIXct(c(1, 9999999), origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00 CET")
y = c(1,2)
df = data.frame(x=x, y=y)
ggplot()+
geom_line(data = df, aes(y=y, x=x))
```

and it produces this output:
[image]

I think it would be intuitive to place the labels mid-month, get rid of mid-month grid lines and so on... a bit like this:
[image]

Can this be accomplished with ggplot2?

Comment: you can set the date_breaks and the date_labels in scale_x_datetime

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get rid of the grid lines I don't want with    scale_x_datetime(date_minor_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b")
But how do I move the labels to the middle and get clearer seperation lines between the month?
 I do not want a grid line where I put my labels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **very** hacky solution, but it's an option. I don't think it's possible to [label on minor breaks only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554942/placement-of-axis-labels-at-minor-breaks-with-ggplot2), so to do what you're looking for, you need to label on major breaks, offset labels with spaces (or maybe tabs), and then hide the minor break panel lines, like so:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = df, aes(y=y, x=x)) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels=paste0("                                                     ","%b")) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Do you also happen to know if there is a way to adjust the length of the seperation lines between the month?

Comment: @PascalIv, you can change the length of all axis ticks with `theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(2,"mm"))`, substituting the length and units you want inside `unit()`. However, that will change both x and y tick marks, which you can't separate, to my knowledge. If you want just the x axis marks to be longer, then you will need to use custom grobs. There are four good solutions here which you could adapt based on your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824773/annotate-ggplot-with-an-extra-tick-and-label